# How to get Yaxis values from highchart

Tags: highcharts

How can I get the y-axis line values from a chart.

Expected values from below chart is [0,250,500,750,1000,1250]

or the difference between two points. Difference between two points is 250 in below chart.
Please help

[image]

Comment: Values that appear on Y-Axis aren't the original values, they're auto generated from highcharts to split Y-Axis into ticks.
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them into `yAxis.tickPositions` or `yAxis.ticks`:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

        console.log(yAxis.tickPositions, yAxis.ticks);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }],
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dvsmghob/